# Creating Contact with photo via EWS Proxy Classes

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server, mapi

I`m tring to create contact via EWS Proxy Classes. All works fine, but i have 1 problem: i can't add contact photo.
I know, that i need to add attachment and set IsContactPhoto property to TRUE, but my AttachmentType proxy class doesn't have it ( or something like that ).
I know how to set this flag via MAPI, but AttachmentType doesn't have ExtendedProperies property, which i need.

Do anyone know how to add contact photo or how to add ExtendedPropery to attachment?

Comment: Flag IsContactPhoto appeared in ES2010. I'm using ProxyClasses whict generated from ES2007 (really need to work with ES2007). So is it possible to create contact with photo?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/createcontactwithpicture.html

It should work even with Exchange 2007 (without IsContactPhoto to set).